# "Proxy server connection failed" in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, proxy, connection, proxy-server

My Google Chrome has stopped working & I don’t know why. `proxy server` part is unchecked & `Automatically detect settings` part of `LAN setting` is checked.
But when I want to load any site on it this message appear:

> Proxy server connection failed.

I searched but no result! Is there any way to solve this problem?

I'm using windows 8.
I uninstalled chrome and Install a newer version, but the same error exists & doesn't allow me to use chrome.
 my connection to Internet is OK & I can ping `www.google.com`, or use other browsers.

Answer (score 7):

Try following these steps:

1. Run Chrome as Administrator.
2. Go to the settings in Chrome.
3. Go to Advanced Settings (its all the way down).
4. Scroll to Network Section and click on ''Change proxy settings''.
5. A window will pop up with the name ''Internet Properties''
6. Click on ''LAN settings''
7. Un-check ''Use a proxy server for your LAN''
8. Check ''Automatically detect settings''
9. Click everything ''OK'' and you are done!

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Click Menu on the upper right side. Beside the STAR symbol (Bookmark).
3. Click Show Advanced Settings.
4. Scroll down and find Network.
5. Click Change proxy settings.
6. On the Connections tab, click LAN settings.
7. Uncheck "Use a proxy server for your LAN."
8. Then click OK.

Hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a freshly installed copy of Chrome.
If nothing works, and your `Use a proxy server your LAN` setting is unchecked, check it and then uncheck it . Believe it or not it might work. I don't know if I should consider it a bug or not.

Answer (score -1):

Internet explorer has a reset to factory button and luckily so does chrome!  try the link below and let us know.  the other option is to stop chrome and delete the c:\users\%username%\appdata\local\google folder entirely then reinstall chrome but this will loose all you local settings and data.

Google doc on how to factory reset:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en

Comment: I do reset setting, but wasn't successful. and the other method wasn't successful too. (I tried to delete that folder but because of administration permission wasn't deleted completely... I use these links, but didn't work ... http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/take-ownership-of-files-folder-and-change-permissions-in-windows-8/    &    http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-xp-tips/you-need-permission-to-perform-this-action/   )

Comment: is there another method?